# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '_ingredients' of 'Dish.Dish(List<Ingredient>)'

Tags: c#, .net

I have this error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
> parameter '_ingredients' of 'Dish.Dish(List)'

My code for now looks like this:

Dish:

```
public class Dish
{
    protected List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    public Dish
        (
        List<Ingredient> _ingredients
        )
    {
        ingredients = _ingredients;
    }
}
```

Soup:

```
public class Soup : Dish
{
    public Soup()
    {
    }
}
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: `public Soup()` is equivalent to `public Soup() : base()` - in other words, trying to call a constructor in the base class without specifying any arguments. There are no such constructors.

Comment: You might want to read https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html, which I wrote a *very* long time ago, but which talks about constructor chaining.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I delete constructor, I getting this error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '_ingredients' of 'Dish.Dish(List<Ingredient>)', but if I add : base(), I get error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '_ingredients' of 'Dish.Dish(List<Ingredient>)' , so what I should do to avoid this error?

Comment: First, make sure you understand the error - basically, you can't construct a `Dish` without specifying a list of ingredients, but that's what you're trying to do. Now to fix the error, make sure you *do* call the base constructor with a list of ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that isn't obvious in C# is that the first thing a constructor does is call a constructor in the parent class

- If you don't provide a constructor, C# provides one for you (but you don't see it)
- If you do provide a constructor, C# does not provide one for you
- If you provide one but it doesn't specify any parent class constructor to call, C# calls the parent parameterless constructor for you
- If there isn't a parameterless constructor for any reason (either you or C# didn't provide one), you get an error.

You naturally get an error at any time that you try and call a constructor that doesn't exist - you just have to remember that sometimes C# is calling constructors for you and you can't see it doing it; you have to remember the rules as to when it does this

---

Examples time:

If you write this:

```
//does not provide a constructor, or what to inherit
class Thing {

}
```

C# internally treats it as this:

```
class Thing: object{         //C# adds "inherits object"
  Thing(): base(){           //C# adds "call base's parameterless constructor"

  }
}
```

---

If you write this:

```
//provide a constructor, that doesn't call any base constructor
class Thing{
  Thing(){

  }
}
```

C# internally treats it as this:

```
class Thing: object{         //again, C# adds "inherits object"
  Thing(): base(){           //again, C# adds "call base's parameterless constructor"

  }
}
```

---

If you write one of these:

```
//class that inherits something, but has no constructor
class Thing: BaseThing{

}

//class that inherits something, and has a constructor
class Thing: BaseThing{
  Thing(){

  }
}

//class that inherits something, and has a constructor that takes arguments
class Thing: BaseThing{
  Thing(string s){

  }
}
```

C# internally treats them as these respectively:

```
class Thing: BaseThing{      //C# doesn't add "inherits object" because your class inherits something else
  Thing(): base(){           //C# adds a constructor that calls base() because you didn't add a constructor

  }
}

class Thing: BaseThing{      //again C# leaves your inheritance alone
  Thing(): base(){           //but it adds base() to the constructor you provided

  }
}

class Thing: BaseThing{      //C# leaves your inheritance alone
  Thing(string s): base(){   //C# adds base() - it doesn't attempt to do anything with any argument like s     

  }
}
```

*In all of these cases, `BaseThing` needs to have a constructor with no parameters* otherwise a call to `base()` doesn't work

If you didn't provide BaseThing with any constructor, then great, C# provides a parameterless one for you. But *if you provide your own constructor, C# doesn't provide one* and that can leave a problem - C# is adding constructors/base calls to your child classes, that call something that might not exist;

Your base constructor takes 1 argument, but C# is adding calls to a constructor that takes 0 arguments - it's not intelligent enough to do anything else. It won't automatically decide what argument to provide to your 1-arg constructor. All it does is put in a call to `base()` and maybe the code stops compiling so you can fix it

---

Your `Dish` has its own constructor, so C# doesn't provide one. This has no influence on what C# will want to do to your Soup. C# will add, to Soup, a "constructor that calls base()" or "add a call to base()" *even though it's wrong and results in code that doesn't compile*, because C# is always striving to fully specify the inheritance hierarchy and constructor chain

- C# always adds "inherits object" if you didnt inherit anything else
- C# always adds a parameterless constructor if you have no constructors, or it adds a call to `base()` on all your constructors that don't call a `base` constructor themselves

You can't fight this mechanism, you can only work with it:

- You either add a parameterless constructor to `Dish`, so that when C# forces a `base()` in `Soup`, there is something to call, or
- You add your own call to `base(...)` in `Soup` so that C# doesn't force a call to `base()`

```
class Dish {
  ...
  Dish() {                                //now any forced constructor/forced base() in Soup  will call this
    _ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
  }
}

class Soup:Dish{

  Soup(): base(new List<Ingredient>()) {  //by calling base(List<Ingredient>) yourself, C# doesn't add a call to base()
    
  }
}
```

Perhaps even, you could make Soup's constructor do something useful: it could ask for a main ingredient, then init the ingredients list and add the ingredient:

```
class Soup:Dish{

  Soup(Ingredient mainIngredient): base(new List<Ingredient>()) {
    _ingredients.Add(mainIngredient);
  }
}
```

Just remember the chain of constructors must be upheld, and that you cannot always see all the code that is being compiled. Commit to memory those things C# adds, that you cannot see, and remember that C# only adds something if you didn't